# USB problems when more than one user logged in (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

Total noob here. I have an odd problem that I can't seem to find any info on anywhere.

I have two user accounts on my machine, call them *userA* and *userB*. Often (but not always?) when *userA* is logged in, if *userB* logs in her keyboard and mouse do not work. I'm pretty sure that all USB ports are not working, since I have tried moving the keyboard and mouse to other ports as well as trying other USB devices. If the machine is rebooted, then the ports start working again.

This never happens if *userA* was not logged in, and it never happens to *userA*, just *userB*. I don't know what to make of it.

I'm not sure what system info, log files etc. to look at to help with diagnosing this issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

As requested, the results of `groups` are:
For *userA*: userA adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
For *userB*: userB sudo

Comment: Can you post the output of `groups` for both users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*userA*'s account was set to automatically log in. After disabling the auto login, the problem seems to be fixed.